# How to set a background image for a window by clicking on the cntl button using wpf?

Tags: wpf, image, background, background-image

I want to set an image as background by clicking the ctrl button?

Any one have ideas? please revert me ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On button click event apply the following code

```
 ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
    myBrush.ImageSource =
        new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image Path"));
    this.Background = myBrush;
```

You can replace the `this` with your control name

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Path/to/image.jpg"));

    ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = imageSource;
    grid.Background = brush;
}
```